# How android.app.Application class work?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I want to know Application class behvaiour, how it work in following cases, any one have idea about it:

- How `android.app.Application` work,
- when it execute in lifecycle of application,
- how it interact with other app component like
  Activity/Service/Receiver.
- How it is usable to improve app performance/architectre?

Comment: All of your four questions are vague

Comment: Way too broad. I'm sure you'll be able to find the answer to most of those questions just by googling them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It starts when your application's process starts and ends when the system kills the process
- It cannot interact with them directly, your may use Broadcasts, or you can get the current Application instance with [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)
- It is a singleton class which is available from every Activity, Service, etc. It's up to you how you use it

Comment: Thanks,...ur right..and also i come to know it call before start of other app component.